# How to fix this issue in a simple HXT function?

Tags: xml, haskell, xml-parsing, hxt

I've started the friendly tutorial [tutorial on HXT](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HXT/Practical/Simple1) to parse XML file with haskell.

In the first page of the tutorial we try to retrieve guest from a xml file. And there is the following function for that.

```
data Guest = Guest {firstName, lastName :: String}
    deriving (Show, Eq)

getGuest = deep (isElem >>> hasName "guest") >>>                                
 proc x -> do                                                                   
    fname <- getText <<< getChildren <<< deep (hasName "fname") -< x            
    lname <- getText <<< getChildren <<< deep (hasName "lname") -< x            
    returnA -< Guest {firstName = fname, lastName = lname}
```

but when I tried to load the file in the interpreter `ghci`. I still get this error :

```
Prelude> :l hxt_tuto.hs
hxt_tuto.hs:15:37: parse error on input `->'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

pointing the fact that operator *->* in the expression `proc x -> do` has a parse error,
I've try many modification without help. like writing all this in a single line

```
getGuest2 = deep (isElem >>> hasName "guest") >>> proc x -> do { fname <- getText <<< getChildren <<< deep (hasName "fname") -< x; lname <- getText <<< getChildren <<< deep (hasName "lname") -< x; returnA -< Guest {firstName = fname, lastName = lname }}
```

Can anybody Help me understand what I've missed ?

thanks for any reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to put

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
```

at the top of your file?